# gradle error Could not find method dependencyManagement()

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Below is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M3'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}


apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-parent:Brixton.SR7'
    }
}

dependencies {


    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka")
    compile "org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:5.5.0"

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

I was using gradle 2.14 and got the below error

```
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.springframework.boot']
   > Spring Boot plugin requires Gradle 3.4 or later. The current version is Gra
dle 2.14
```

Then I upgraded gradle to 3.4 as suggested in the error message.

Now I get the below error

> Could not find method dependencyManagement() for arguments [build_79bcact4bkf1
>   sckkod1j3zl7l$_run_closure1@4a2d71c9] on root project 'myproject'
>   of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Is the method `dependencyManagement()` no longer available in gradle 3.4 ? 
If anybody is aware of the alternate method to be used in gradle 3.4 , kindly revert

Comment: This method does come from gradle itself, but from spring plugin. Have a look here: https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To use this `DSL` you have to provide the dependency-management-plugin:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      jcenter() //or mavenCentral()
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.3.RELEASE"
  }
}

apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
```

Or you can use:

```
plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.3.RELEASE"
}
```

More [details here.](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin)

Comment: For anyone that has recently upgraded from Spring Boot 1.x to 2.x:  You are not required to apply the dependency management plugin individually in Spring Boot 1.x. This was changed in Spring Boot 2.x as documented [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#dependency-management)

Answer (score 3):

For me the fix was replacing the distributionUrl in the gradle-wrapper.properties with:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip`

and updating the dependencies in the build.gradle file to:

`dependencies { classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4" }`

Answer (score 2):

In Gradle 7 this error is also caused by importing a BOM using:

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "tech.jhipster:jhipster-dependencies:${jhipsterDependenciesVersion}"
    }
}
```

In Gradle 7 you need to import your BOM in the following way:

```
implementation platform("tech.jhipster:jhipster-dependencies:${jhipsterDependenciesVersion}")
```