# What??? Missing argument 'Gradle' in settings.gradle

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, build, admob

I got an error building my unity project due to an error with the settings.gradle file.

See more details here:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\settings.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'Gradle'.
> Could not find method dependencyResolutionManagement() for arguments [settings_9y2goy45mvwak9gvumvg94pgc$_run_closure1@4aecf086] on settings 'Gradle' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

When I went to the settings.gradle file it displays this.

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

include ':launcher', ':unityLibrary'
include 'unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib'


dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
        
        google()
        mavenCentral()
// Android Resolver Repos Start
        def unityProjectPath = $/file:////$.replace("\\", "/")
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com/" // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml:7, Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleUmpDependencies.xml:7
        }
        mavenLocal()
// Android Resolver Repos End
        flatDir {
            dirs "${project(':unityLibrary').projectDir}/libs"
        }
    }
}
```

As it shows in the file it doesn't contain the argument Gradle but it seems it have a GoogleMobileAds library. Is this normal?? What is missing??

One more thing, there is an extended version of he problem here:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.2.6f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.2.6f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "bundleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\settings.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'Gradle'.
> Could not find method dependencyResolutionManagement() for arguments [settings_9y2goy45mvwak9gvumvg94pgc$_run_closure1@4aecf086] on settings 'Gradle' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <aa9f40e1a34f4b01ac44d2ce67124834>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <aa9f40e1a34f4b01ac44d2ce67124834>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <aa9f40e1a34f4b01ac44d2ce67124834>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <aa9f40e1a34f4b01ac44d2ce67124834>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <aa9f40e1a34f4b01ac44d2ce67124834>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <aa9f40e1a34f4b01ac44d2ce67124834>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <aa9f40e1a34f4b01ac44d2ce67124834>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <aa9f40e1a34f4b01ac44d2ce67124834>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <aa9f40e1a34f4b01ac44d2ce67124834>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <aa9f40e1a34f4b01ac44d2ce67124834>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput buildProgramOutput) (at <aa9f40e1a34f4b01ac44d2ce67124834>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <aa9f40e1a34f4b01ac44d2ce67124834>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <52409df47eec4ff4a3e5a5be37682d54>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gradle error Could not find method dependencyManagement()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214689/gradle-error-could-not-find-method-dependencymanagement)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use Unity 2022.3 or higher.
For older versions, you will need to do the following:

1. Go to `Assets/Plugins/Android` directory and delete `gradleTemplate`, `mainTemplate` and `settingsTemplate` files. (Or move somewhere as backup).
2. Go to `Edit -> Project Settings... -> Player`
3. Open `Android` tab and then open `Publishing Settings`
4. Tick `Custom Main Gradle Template` and `Custom Gradele Properties Template`
5. `Assets -> External Dependency Manager -> Android Resolver -> Force Resolve`

You most likely opened a project that was created in newer Unity version. Your Unity 2021.2.6f1 depends on a very old Gradle version that doesn't have `dependencyResolutionManagement()`. By deleting gradle templates and generating them again, Unity will generate templates that are correct for the current version.

`dependencyResolutionManagement` was added in Gradle 6.8 and your unity version uses Gradle 6.1.1 [source](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html)

Comment: This is helpful!! Look, what happened is that the first version of the project was in 2021.2.6f1 but then I decided to upgrade the version to 2022.3.15f1. The thing is that time later I installed an external library asset and when I wanted to build the first time in the latest version It started to give me another error. So I passed the 2022.3 project to 2021.2.6f1 just to see if that solved my problem but as you see it doesn't help. Happily, I made a backup of the 2022.3 version so I can send you the error I get but I don't know where to send you because the message is too long.

Comment: Try doing the same. Delete 'Template' files from `Assets/Plugins/Android` and then regenerate them from Settings. Older Unity versions cannot upgrade gradle templates automatically, and this needs to be done every time when Unity changes gradle configuration files. If it doesn't help and if the error is different, you can create a new question and leave a link to it.

Comment: I just followed your steps and it gave me a new error but I think it is much more readable. The link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77922283/update-on-unity-gradle-project) . It says that I have to add a code to the build.gradle file but I'm not quite sure if this is what is needed.  I want to thank you for helping me with this and I would be very pleased if you could read the post.