# Update on Unity Gradle project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, build

I've just applied some changes to my unity problem:

1. Deleted all 'Template' files from `Assets/Plugins/Android`
2. I regenerated the files by going to `Edit -> Project Settings -> Player` and in the `Android Tab` I went to `Publishing Settings` where I ticked the `Custom Main Gradle Template` and `Custom Gradle Properties Template`
3. Then I went to `Assets -> External Dependency Manager -> Android Resolver -> Force Resolve`

When I tried to make the build it failed giving me this 2 messages.

```
> Configure project :launcher
WARNING:The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is deprecated.
The current default is 'true'.
It will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You can add the following to your build.gradle instead:
android {
    packagingOptions {
        jniLibs {
            useLegacyPackaging = true
        }
    }
}
WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33

This Android Gradle plugin (7.1.2) was tested up to compileSdk = 32

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 33

> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:writeReleaseApplicationId UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:analyticsRecordingRelease
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:writeReleaseAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processApplicationManifestReleaseForBundle UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToDirRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:writeReleaseAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:bundleReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:prepareReleaseArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:configureReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:parseReleaseIntegrityConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:writeReleaseAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
58 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 56 up-to-date

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

The second one.

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
                          ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: package androidx.annotation
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
                          ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: package androidx.annotation
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:8: error: package com.revenuecat.purchases does not exist
import com.revenuecat.purchases.CustomerInfo;
                               ^
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:9: error: package com.revenuecat.purchases does not exist
import com.revenuecat.purchases.DangerousSettings;
                               ^
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:10: error: package com.revenuecat.purchases does not exist
import com.revenuecat.purchases.Purchases;
                               ^
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:11: error: package com.revenuecat.purchases does not exist
import com.revenuecat.purchases.Store;
                               ^
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:12: error: package com.revenuecat.purchases.common does not exist
import com.revenuecat.purchases.common.PlatformInfo;
                                      ^
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:13: error: package com.revenuecat.purchases.hybridcommon does not exist
import com.revenuecat.purchases.hybridcommon.CommonKt;
                                            ^
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:14: error: package com.revenuecat.purchases.hybridcommon does not exist
import com.revenuecat.purchases.hybridcommon.ErrorContainer;
                                            ^
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:15: error: package com.revenuecat.purchases.hybridcommon does not exist
import com.revenuecat.purchases.hybridcommon.OnResult;
                                            ^
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:16: error: package com.revenuecat.purchases.hybridcommon does not exist
import com.revenuecat.purchases.hybridcommon.OnResultAny;
                                            ^
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:17: error: package com.revenuecat.purchases.hybridcommon does not exist
import com.revenuecat.purchases.hybridcommon.OnResultList;
                                            ^
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:18: error: package com.revenuecat.purchases.hybridcommon does not exist
import com.revenuecat.purchases.hybridcommon.SubscriberAttributesKt;
                                            ^
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:19: error: package com.revenuecat.purchases.hybridcommon.mappers does not exist
import com.revenuecat.purchases.hybridcommon.mappers.CustomerInfoMapperKt;
                                                    ^
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:20: error: package com.revenuecat.purchases.hybridcommon.mappers does not exist
import com.revenuecat.purchases.hybridcommon.mappers.MappersHelpersKt;
                                                    ^
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:21: error: package com.revenuecat.purchases.interfaces does not exist
import com.revenuecat.purchases.interfaces.UpdatedCustomerInfoListener;
                                          ^
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
    private static UpdatedCustomerInfoListener listener = new UpdatedCustomerInfoListener() {
                   ^
  symbol:   class UpdatedCustomerInfoListener
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:446: error: cannot find symbol
    private static void sendError(ErrorContainer error, String method) {
                                  ^
  symbol:   class ErrorContainer
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:466: error: cannot find symbol
    private static void sendErrorPurchase(ErrorContainer errorContainer) {
                                          ^
  symbol:   class ErrorContainer
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:478: error: cannot find symbol
    private static OnResult getLogInListener(final String method) {
                   ^
  symbol:   class OnResult
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:503: error: cannot find symbol
    private static OnResult getCustomerInfoListener(final String method) {
                   ^
  symbol:   class OnResult
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:518: error: cannot find symbol
    private static DangerousSettings getDangerousSettingsFromJSON(String dangerousSettingsJSON) {
                   ^
  symbol:   class DangerousSettings
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:109: error: cannot find symbol
                                       @Nullable final String oldSKU,
                                        ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:112: error: cannot find symbol
                                       @Nullable final String presentedOfferingIdentifier) {
                                        ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:141: error: cannot find symbol
                                       @Nullable final String oldSKU,
                                        ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:172: error: cannot find symbol
                                           @Nullable final String oldSKU,
                                            ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:175: error: cannot find symbol
                                           @Nullable final String offerIdentifier
                                            ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:477: error: cannot find symbol
    @NonNull
     ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:502: error: cannot find symbol
    @NonNull
     ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:517: error: cannot find symbol
    @Nullable
     ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
    private static UpdatedCustomerInfoListener listener = new UpdatedCustomerInfoListener() {
                                                              ^
  symbol:   class UpdatedCustomerInfoListener
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
        public void onReceived(@NonNull CustomerInfo customerInfo) {
                                        ^
  symbol: class CustomerInfo
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
        public void onReceived(@NonNull CustomerInfo customerInfo) {
                                ^
  symbol: class NonNull
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:53: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
            sendCustomerInfo(CustomerInfoMapperKt.map(customerInfo), RECEIVE_CUSTOMER_INFO);
                             ^
  symbol: variable CustomerInfoMapperKt
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
        PlatformInfo platformInfo = new PlatformInfo(PLATFORM_NAME, PLUGIN_VERSION);
        ^
  symbol:   class PlatformInfo
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
        PlatformInfo platformInfo = new PlatformInfo(PLATFORM_NAME, PLUGIN_VERSION);
                                        ^
  symbol:   class PlatformInfo
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
        Store store = useAmazon ? Store.AMAZON : Store.PLAY_STORE;
        ^
  symbol:   class Store
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
        Store store = useAmazon ? Store.AMAZON : Store.PLAY_STORE;
                                  ^
  symbol:   variable Store
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
        Store store = useAmazon ? Store.AMAZON : Store.PLAY_STORE;
                                                 ^
  symbol:   variable Store
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
        DangerousSettings dangerousSettings = getDangerousSettingsFromJSON(dangerousSettingsJSON);
        ^
  symbol:   class DangerousSettings
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
        CommonKt.configure(UnityPlayer.currentActivity,
        ^
  symbol:   variable CommonKt
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
        Purchases.getSharedInstance().setUpdatedCustomerInfoListener(listener);
        ^
  symbol:   variable Purchases
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated - copia (2)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\revenuecat\purchasesunity\PurchasesWrapper.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
            CommonKt.getProductInfo(productIds, type, new OnResultList() {
      <message truncated>
```

I'm using the version 2022.3.15f1 of Unity and the External Dependency Manager 1.2.177.

Thank you so much for your time.

To see the original post click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77804040/what-missing-argument-gradle-in-settings-gradle?noredirect=1)

Comment: According to errors, the following libraries are missing `androidx.annotation:annotation` and `com.revenuecat.purchases:purchases-hybrid-common`. But it shouldn't happen because you have run Android Resolver. Can you please share your `mainTemplate.gradle` file contents?

Comment: I added the file as an answer. You can go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77929319/23169220)

Comment: Just to take into account, now that you mention revenuecat. I installed an external package of the billing library a time ago. Then I uninstalled it but it looks that some files have been modified. Do you know how I can solve this?? I'm not really interested in keeping the revenuecat extension.

Comment: Package Manager must uninstall it correctly. Or if you have installed it from unitypackage than just deleting revenuecat's directory from Assets should be enough. But according to logs, revenuecat is still present in the generated Android project. Try deleting `Library` folder from your project and then building again, Unity will generate the project again.

Also, it is better to add logs to the question by editing it, not to the answers, local mods not going to like it.

Comment: Added answer below, I think it should be solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `PurchasesWrapper` from RevenueCat plugin remained in the project, but dependencies that it requires are gone. Maybe it is due to cache, or maybe it is due to incomplete uninstallation.

1. Try to delete `Library` directory and then rebuild the project in case if this file was cached.
2. Check if you have `RevenueCat` directory in the project's `Assets` folder and delete it.
3. If the above will not help, in case if you moved RevenueCat's files some time ago, search for `PurchasesWrapper.java` in your `Assets` folder and delete it.

Comment: IT WORKED!!!! What I did was delete the `RevenueCat` folder from the `Assets` folder. Men, I'm blind I don't know how I didn't see it. Thank you so much!!! I've been struggling with this problem for about two months and seeing my game compiling gives me a huge relief. Thank you again for helping me and I hope one day I can return the favor to you!! Blessings.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code in the mainTemplate.gradle file

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
**APPLY_PLUGINS**

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
**DEPS**}

android {
    ndkPath "**NDKPATH**"

    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion **MINSDKVERSION**
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        ndk {
            abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
        }
        versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
        versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD**
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = **BUILTIN_NOCOMPRESS** + unityStreamingAssets.tokenize(', ')
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }**PACKAGING_OPTIONS**
}
**IL_CPP_BUILD_SETUP**
**SOURCE_BUILD_SETUP**
**EXTERNAL_SOURCES**
```